# How to get email id from linkedin API?

Tags: iphone, ios, linkedin-api

I have integrated the Linkedin login in my iPhone application. i need to get email id using the linkedin api. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you would need to add the `r_emailaddress` scope to your authentication request, as follows:

`https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress`